# SailsJS + AngularJS (registration) - How to return object from SailsJS Action to AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, callback, sails.js, middleware

I was trying to implement redirection to the new user profile using angularJS; however, I was not able to return user object from Sails Action to angular after the user was successfully created. As a result, I do not have the user id in order to render the page using angular.

I am using default SailsJS architecture.

Here is my **Angular** code in **SignUpController.js** (I know that it's not the best idea to make http requests in controller)

```
angular.module('SignupModule').controller('SignupController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

$scope.submitSignupForm = function (){
  console.log("clicked");
  $scope.successMessage = false;
  $scope.errorMesaage   = false;

  $http.post('/signup', {
    name: $scope.signupForm.name,
    pass: $scope.signupForm.pass
  }).then (function onSuccess(res){

    $scope.successMessage = true;

    // render the profile of a new user 
    // did not get user object from sails
    // res object return status of request but not user object 

  }).catch(function onError(res){
    $scope.errorMesaage   = true;
  })
}

});
```

Here is my **SailsJS** code in **UserController.js**.( I was trying to return res.send() and res.json() but it doesn't work.)

```
module.exports = {

//create new user
create: function (req, res, next) {

  //check if user exists
  User.findOne({name: req.param('name')}).exec(function findOneCB(err, found){
    if(err) return next(err);

    //if user does not exist create one; otherwise exit
    if(!found){

    User.create (req.params.all(), function userCreated(err, user){
        if(err) return next(err);

        /* return user object to angular */

        //return res.send(user);
        //return res.json(user);
      });
    } else {
      return next();
    }
   });
  }
};
```

here is **config/routes.js**

```
  'GET /signup': {
   view: 'signup'
  },
  'POST /signup': {
    controller: 'UserController',
    action: 'create'
   },
```

The workflow should look something like this:

- User Clicked on submit button
- submitSignupForm creates a post request to '/signup'
- Sails handles this request in routes.js
- Sails creates new user via Sails PostgreSQL adapter
- Sails returns the user object to AngularJS !!! - does not work
- AngularJS renders a user profile page using user.id !!! - does not work

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

```
module.exports = {
    create: function (req, res) {
        User.findOne({name: req.param('name')}).exec(function findOneCB(err, found) {
            if (err) return res.negotiate(err);

            if (!found) {

                User.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err, user) {
                    if (err) res.negotiate({error:err});

                    return res.ok(user);
                });
            } else {
                return res.negotiate({error:new Error("USER_EXIST")});
            }
        });
    }
};
```